# Converting characters to hexadecimal

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I'm trying to convert a ciphertext (from AES encryption) into a hexadecimal value.

I'm using the following code (state is the ciphertext) for the conversion:

```
foreach(char *v, state) {
    printf("%02X", *v);
}
```

For this ciphertext:

```
    '4¥W[™úËj$Ó¶U6
```

I get this output:

```
    2734FFFFFFA5575BFFFFFF99FFFFFFFAFFFFFFCB6A240BFFFFFFD318FFFFFFB65536
```

Which is not the correct hex form for this ciphertext. I tried other conversion methods which all leads to the same result.

EDIT:
foreach code:

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
for(int keep = 1, \
count = 0,\
size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
keep && count != size; \
keep = !keep, count++) \
for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
```

Comment: Your value needs to be unsigned, otherwise you're extended the sign bit. cast `*v` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: That `foreach` macro might win some kind of least-maintainable code award.

Comment: This is a pretty bad way of using a macro. Besides the fact that you have at least one error within the definition - `sizeof *(array)`, and one error in the way you are invoking it - `foreach(char *v, state)`, it is literally impossible to follow and understand what you are trying to do in it. Write it down as a normal function, and the problem will most likely be revealed (and if not, then you could still easily debug your code and find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not C, there's no `foreach` in C. It might be C++, in which case the problem is that the argument to `printf()`'s `%x` conversion specifier is being sign-extended. Your platform likely has a signed `char` type.

Cast the value to `unsigned char`.

Comment: True, I forgot to add the foreach macro.